# Getting error while joining two tables

Tags: users, database

Here is query which is, I am using

```
$query = db_select('users','u');
$query->join('users_roles', 'u.uid = users_roles.uid'); // JOIN users_roles with users
$query->fields('users', array('name','uid')) // SELECT the field name from users
    ->condition('users_roles.rid', 5);   

  $results = $query->execute();
```

Actually i want the user name and id for that those user who are under role id = 5

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066
>   Not unique table/alias: 'u': SELECT users.name AS name, users.uid AS
>   uid FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {users_roles} u.uidusers_roles.uid WHERE
>   (users_roles.rid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array (
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 5 ) in user_assign_list() (line 80 of
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\nic\sites\all\modules\user_assign\user_assign.module).

This error shown on the browser. Actually i am creating the custom module file for this requirement. Is there any need to include sql connection for those custom module?
here is .module file

```
<?php
function user_assign_permission() {
  return array(
    'submit user_assign' => array(
      'title' => t('Submit user_assign'),
      'description' => t('Submit the user_assign form'),
    ),
    'access user_assign list' => array(
      'title' => t('Access user_assign list'),
      'description' => t('Access the user_assign submissions'),
    ),

  );
}
function user_assign_menu() {
  $items = array();

   $items['users-list'] = array(
    'title' => t('User Assign'),
    'page callback' => 'user_assign_list',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'access arguments' => array('access user_assign list'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}


function user_assign_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'user_assign_function' => array(
      'variables' => array('rows' => NULL),
    ),
    'user_assign_template' => array(
      'variables' => array('rows' => NULL),
      'template' => 'user_assign_template',
    ),


  );
}



function theme_user_assign_function($variables)
{
    $output = '';

//   print_r($variables);
    foreach($variables['items'] as $row) {

     $output .= '<div class="views-row"><div class="do_featured">
   <div class="do_title">
    <span>    <div class="field"><div class="field-items">'.$row[1].'&nbsp'.$row[2].'</div></div>
    </span> 
   </div></div>';



    }

    return $output;
}

function user_assign_list() {
 // $query = db_select('users', 'n');

//  $query->condition('n.empname', '%' . db_like($_GET['empname']). '%','LIKE');

 // $query->fields('n', array('fe_id', 'empcode','empname','empphoto','empemail','empdesignation'))
  //    ->limit(4)
  //    ->addTag('node_access')
  //    ->groupBy('n.fe_id');
$query = db_select('users','u');
$query->join('users_roles', 'u.uid = users_roles.uid'); // JOIN users_roles with users
$query->fields('users', array('name','uid')) // SELLECT the field name from users
    ->condition('users_roles.rid', 5);


  $results = $query->execute();
     $rows = array();
  foreach($results as $result)
  {
    $rows[] = array(
        $result->uid,
        $result->name,
        );

  }
  $output = theme('user_assign_function', array('items' => $rows));
  return $output;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Sumit check the below query and it not showing any error.

Use [Query coder](https://www.drupal.org/project/query_coder) module to create any query in drupal format

[Query coder](https://www.drupal.org/project/query_coder) Convert SQL query to Drupal Database abstraction layer code.

$query = db_select('users','u');

$query->join('users_roles', 'r', 'u.uid = r.uid'); // JOIN users_roles with users

$query->fields('u', array('name','uid')) // SELECT the field name from users
    ->condition('r.rid', 5);

$results = $query->execute();
     $rows = array();

foreach($results as $result)
  {

```
$rows[] = array(
    $result->uid,
    $result->name,
    );
```

}